# How to print/display the hashmap in workday studio?

Tags: hashmap, workday-api

I am using a hashmap in a Workday studio as below:

```
props['Classification'] = parts[0].xpath('wd:All_Positions_group/wd:Classification')     
props['HashValue'] = props['Classification']
props['HashKey'] = parts[0].xpath('wd:All_Positions_group/wd:Position_ID' )
props['position.hash.map'].put(props['HashKey'], props['HashValue'])
```

Is there any way to display/print the entire hashmap or the array after the load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design choice to use a HashMap here is probably a mistake - and you should revisit that choice.

If you wish to print out the contents of the map for diagnostic purposes use the toString() method on it

```
props['position.hash.map'].toString()
```

which will print out the contents as described at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#toString-- .  That you didn't look in the JavaDoc before asking this question is another indication that you aren't entirely prepared for using HashMaps in this code and that you should be looking at alternatives